# My program in vb.net often end abruptly. How to find end command?

Tags: vb.net

I think there is an end command somewhere that I miss and got called.

However, how to find it.

If I search for end then there are so many end. End sub, end function.

I just want the program to break just before abruptly end.

Is this because of some out of memory or what?

The program run in debug mode. Suddenly it ends. So it runs 100 threads and then the vb 2012 is still running but the program have stopped. As if someone press the stop button or some end statement reached.

Comment: How abruptly are we talking about? If the program just up and disappears with no warning or message whatsoever, that's characteristic of a stack fault.  Try running your program in a debugger and watch what exceptions happen.

Comment: Use a decent disassembler (Reflector, ILSpy) and search for Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.EndApp.  Look at the exitcode of your program with a debugger or a little test app.  It will be an exception code if the program failed due to a hard uncatchable crash.

Comment: Are you running in Debug or Release mode? I've mostly seen this when running in Release mode and you won't even get an Unhandled Exception message to trace the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `End` and ignore `End Sub` etc. you can search using regular expressions (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)

```
End\r?$
```

Finds `End` at the end of a line. Interestingly, it's exactly the example in the [MSDN regex page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your technology stack, try overriding the OnExit method:

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e) {
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
```

Set a break point on the base.onExit(e); line and then look in the call stack.  Or if you aren't in the debugger, write to a message box the previously called method.

Comment: What is your context? I tried this in winforms and it's not a member of `Form`.

Comment: @DanVerdolino WPF was the context.  This one is in the App.Xaml class