# Why I cannot find end command in vb.net with this regular expression End\r?$

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

A long time ago I have put an end command somewhere.

Not just end sub or end for or end if. The end command

Something like asked here

[My program in vb.net often end abruptly. How to find end command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441911/my-program-in-vb-net-often-end-abruptly-how-to-find-end-command)

And the answer there ask to find

```
End\r?$
```

I did.

To make sure that the find fail to find the end command and simply that there is no end command in my program I add another End command and tell visual studio to find that end command.

This is the screenshot

Visual studio 2022

[image]

Doesn't work. In the picture you can clearly see an End statement before an End Function statement. Visual studio cannot find it.

Trying to find Next and everything that's also obviously there don't work.

Say I search for Next\r?$

It can't find any Next

In the picture you c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to turn on regex search

the `.*` thing below search box
to read more about it [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)
[image: regex on]

[image: regex off]